# Use Nuget to download artifacts (similarly to maven)

Tags: c#, .net, maven, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I have a C# .NET project that has some dependencies on some dlls that I currently acquire by downloading a third party zip from an internal location (*host:port/downloads/api/MyProjectV1_1.zip*) and copying manually all the relevant dlls from there to a common area in my solution so that I can use them as dependencies.

I have an equivalent implementation of the same project in java and for the java dependencies I use maven.
I was directed to NuGet for an equivalent performance in the windows world but after reading some supporting documents I'm still unsure about how to proceed.

For starters I'm not sure about how what I want translates into NuGet terms, they have several supporting documents but I couldn't match any to my requirements. 
Do I need to create a NuGet.org account? I'm using JFrog for maven. I'm specifically targeting the ability to download NuGet packages from JFrog (the artifacts I mentioned above *'host:port/downloads/api/MyProjectV1_1.zip'* are also in JFrog '*artifactory.net/artifactory/webapp/artifacts/browse/tree/General/nuget-libs-snapshots-local/MyProject/V1_1/MyProject.x64.V11.snapshot.1.1.0.nupkg*')

**Among the things I tried:**

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2011/08/easy-way-to-set-up-nuget-to-restore.html

```
PM>  Enable-PackageRestore
Failed to add import 'NuGet.targets' to commonDlls
Failed to add import 'NuGet.targets' to MyProject
```

Even if it wasn't failing upon the above, I still don't see how this would work since there's no information regarding the artifactory if I follow these instructions.

http://blog.davidebbo.com/2014/01/the-right-way-to-restore-nuget-packages.html

Something like the config below would package the sources (and upload/publish) rather than download.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/" />
    <add key="aspnetwebstacknightlyrelease" value="https://www.myget.org/f/aspnetwebstacknightlyrelease/" />
  </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Can you provide some guidance regarding the steps I should take in order to achieve maven-like behavior?

Answer (score 0):

First off, I am making the assumption that you are properly creating and publishing your NuGet packages.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package)

It looks like JFrog provides for the ability to host NuGet packages, so you should be able to use JFrog if you create a new NuGet based Artifactory that you can publish your NuGet packages to.
(https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/NuGet+Repositories)

Once you have your NuGet artifactory set up, you need to add it as a package source. To do so, in Visual Studio, you can:

1. Right click your project
2. Select Manage Nuget Packages
3. Click the settings wheel in the upper right
4. A new window should pop up.
5. Click the + button in the top right
6. Name the new package source whatever you want
7. Point the source to your JFrog Nuget Artifactory
8. Click Update (this is important, if you do not click Update, it won't save)

You only need to do the above steps once to add a new package source. Once you have your new source added, you can:

1. Right click your project
2. Click Manage Nuget Packages
3. Select the Browse tab in the upper left
4. In the package source dropdown, select your JFrog NuGet Artifactory
5. You should now see your JFrog NuGet packages available to install into your project.

NuGet also has a CLI that you can use. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference)

I hope that is what you were looking for :)

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for the above, however, I am not very interested in publishing my project via NuGet, what I want is to use it in a way that its dependencies are pointing to a central place (e.g artifactor/api//nuget/trunk) rather than having to update all the dlls each time there is an upgrade for the dependencies. Those dependencies are indeed in JFrog artifactory already, so I just need a way to utilise NuGet to do that.